# The mobile app shows too informative login error messages

Tags: bug, security, mobile-app

Today when I was moving to a new Android phone, I have noticed that when I typed my account password incorrectly, the message I have received was "Error while attempting to login: Bad password".

Out of curiosity I have decided to try to use invalid email address. The message I have received was "Error while attempting to login: Invalid Email [example@example.com]".

I was trying to login using the StackExchange login. As mentioned by `animuson` in comments this most likely suggests that the API is leaking information on whatever the account exists or not exists, which goes against advices on [OWASP Authentication](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.md#authentication-responses).

Related read: [security.stackexchange.com: “Username and/or Password Invalid” - Why do websites show this kind of message instead of informing the user which one was wrong?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/username-and-or-password-invalid-why-do-websites-show-this-kind-of-message-i)

Comment: The mobile app is deprecated. Use the mobile web site or the new responsive site.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The problem is the mobile app actually gets those messages from the API, which *anyone* can use and basically run a list of email addresses to see which ones are registered with us. The mobile apps are somewhat irrelevant here.